# No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, opensuse

I am using python3 and have installed tensorflow-gpu using:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

And have checked that it is installed by:

```
pip3 show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.13.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for 
everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-estimator, keras-applications, termcolor, absl-py, six, 
astor, protobuf, wheel, keras-preprocessing, gast, grpcio, numpy, 
tensorboard
Required-by:
```

but when I do the following it gives me an error:

```
user:/home/mydirectory # python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 31 2018, 19:45:04) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, 
in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'
```

I see from the error that its looking for tensorflow in directory

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow
```

But pip indicates that its installed at

```
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is the `#` in `user:/home/mydirectory #` mean root user in this case? If so, there might be different configurations for root compared to your user.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Please specify the version also?

Comment: Can it be that your distro has removed the symlink `/{usr,}/lib -> /{usr,}/lib64` recently and the migration didn't go smoothly? `/lib` should be for 32bit stuff only. Can you also add the output of `python3.6 -m site` to the question?

Comment: @Harry Boy please try to install with root or sudo.                                            then try pip3 --version                                                                                          shekh@shekh:~$ pip3 --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)                                               shekh@shekh:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Answer (score 4):

```
Please follow below steps..
0) please login with root permission or sudo and write this command in terminal 

1)pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1   

2)pip3 --version
  pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)   
3)shekh@shekh:~$ python3
  Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
```

[https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NxB2.png)

[image: for reference]

[image: tensorflow test run]

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/374

Are you opening the terminal from within the tensorflow directory?

"Actually I had this issue because I was trying to import tensorflow from a python session inside the tensorflow repo folder, going to some other folder and starting python and importing tensorflow worked for me."

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error and it was solved with this command

**python2**:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

**python3**:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error on a **Windows 10** system.

There, I had a second `tensorflow` install under `AppData\Roaming\Python\...`. This install was likely a product of some previous work that I did not clean up properly, so for me, removing the content of the `site-packages` directory solved the issue. After that I could `import tensorflow` without any problems.